# How to make a Google Map (Using Javascript API v3) including geolocation and a KML layer? I can only get one or the other

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The following code is what I have been trying, but I can only get one or the other I am unable to get geolocation to work with a kml layer as well. I change the order of the map and kml layer and it only shows whichever one is last in the code. Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Geolocation</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var initialLocation;
  var siberia = new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105);
  var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);
  var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
  var map;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kml/everything.kml');
georssLayer.setMap(map);


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



    // Try W3C Geolocation method (Preferred)
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      browserSupportFlag = true;
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        contentString = "";
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
        infowindow.open(map);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
      });
    } else if (google.gears) {
      // Try Google Gears Geolocation
      browserSupportFlag = true;
      var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
      geo.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);
        contentString = "";
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
        infowindow.open(map);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      browserSupportFlag = false;
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    }
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      initialLocation = newyork;
      contentString = "Error: The Geolocation service failed.";
    } else {
      initialLocation = siberia;
      contentString = "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation. Are you in Siberia?";
    }
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(initialLocation);
    infowindow.open(map);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The displayed map will only show whichever of these comes last:

```
var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mymedicinalgarden.org/kml/everything.kml');
georssLayer.setMap(map);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

I really need the KML layer in addition to using geolocation. I know there is a way with the correct syntax, but after hours of research and trial and error the solution escapes me. Please help

Comment: Whichever item comes last overrides the previous one. If "var georssLayer" is last, the KML layer removes and replaces geolocation data. If "var map" is last geolocation data removes and replaces the KML layer. The trick is to combine the two- as of yet NO SUCCESS. Can anyone tell me how to correctly write the code to include BOTH ELEMENTS not one or the other? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should first set the map.

and then load kml on the map

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://example.org/kml/everything.kml');
georssLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I have tried this, what happens is the map geolocates and then moves the center position to center of the the kml file not the geolocation coordinates. So once again, I get one or the other not BOTH. As soon as the KML file is loaded I lose the geolocation. I have even tried stripping the <lookat> tag from the KML with same result. I need the kml to center on the geolocation coordinates not center on itself... Very Frustrating Thanks for the suggestion though...

Comment: Whichever item comes last overrides the previous one. If "var georssLayer" is last, the KML layer removes and replaces geolocation data. If "var map" is last geolocation data removes and replaces the KML layer. The trick is to combine the two- as of yet NO SUCCESS. Can anyone tell me how to correctly write the code to include BOTH ELEMENTS not one or the other? Thanks in advance

Comment: while loading kmlLayer, there is an option "preserveViewport", set the option to true so the map viewport will not be changed. And later set map's center to geolocaiton point. The steps to follow: Load the map, load kml with preserveViewport to true, set your geolocation.